# How does step() in R handle interactions and categorical variables?

Tags: r, regression, lm

I have fit a linear regression `lm` with multiple interactions in `R`.

Now, I want to do variable selection. For this, I intend to use the `step`-function.

However, I am unsure how exactly `step` deals with interactions. I want the selction procedure to be hierarchical in the following sense:

- If the interactions u:v is kept, so are u and v themselves
- For dummy variables x1 and x2, if x1 is kept so is x2 and vice versa

How can I ensure this? Is it already implemented this way?

Comment: See my answer if it's helpful.

Comment: Yes thanks just saw it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regsubsets` to get all possible models with stepwise regression, and take a subset of those which satisfy your requirements. For example, when only two-way interactions are considered, you can use the following approach to satisfy the first requirement:

```
require(leaps)
require(stringr)
tmp <- regsubsets(mpg ~ (wt + drat + disp + qsec)*(wt + drat + disp + qsec), data=mtcars, nbest=1000, really.big=T, intercept=T)
df <- summary(tmp)[[1]]
df <- as.data.frame(sapply(as.data.frame(df), as.numeric))

#for all columns in df which have ':' in the name, that is an interaction column
#if such a column is 1, each of the component columns must also be 1
comb_cols <- grep(":", names(df), value = TRUE)
for (i in 1:length(comb_cols)) {
  this_comb <- comb_cols[i]
  left_comp <- str_sub(this_comb, start = 1, end = str_locate(this_comb, ":")[1]-1)
  right_comp <- str_sub(this_comb, start = str_locate(this_comb, ":")[1]+1, end =  nchar(this_comb))
  df[,left_comp] <- ifelse(df[,this_comb]==1, 1, df[,left_comp])
  df[,right_comp] <- ifelse(df[,this_comb]==1, 1, df[,right_comp])
}
df <- df[!duplicated(df),]
```

Then from `summary(tmp)` extract only the models which are in df.